# JavaScript: how to call a function on the prototype property, from inside another function on the prototype property, all inside a closure?

Tags: javascript, scope, closures, prototype

I am hoping that someone can help me figure out how to do this correctly, rather than just "make it work."

I am trying to use an object inside a closure, and having scope issues:

```
var Why = function() {
    this.foo = 'bar';
}
Why.prototype.explain = function () {
    alert(this.foo);
}
Why.prototype.doIt = function () {
    this.explain();
}

(function() {

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
        var why = new Why();
        why.doIt();
    });

})();
```

And I get in console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.explain is not a function
```

I could use

```
Why.prototype.explain.call();
```

but that just seems wrong, and when I actually do that... *this.foo is undefined anyway,* so it's obviously not the right approach.

If I remove the self calling function as follows...

```
var Why = function() {
    this.foo = 'bar';
}
Why.prototype.explain = function () {
    console.log(this.foo);
}
Why.prototype.doIt = function () {
    // Why.prototype.explain.call();
    this.explain();
}

// (function() {

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
        var why = new Why();
        why.doIt();
    });

// })();
```

then it works of course, but:

***what am I missing and where/how can I learn it?***

Thanks in advance.

Comment: simple: add semi colons after assignments, you won't believe what is happening...

Answer (score 2):

Your code is parsed as

```
Why.prototype.doIt = function () { ... }(function() { ... });
```

You're calling the function you want to assign to the prototype, then assigning its return value.  Since it returns `undefined`, `Why.prototype.doIt` doesn't exist.

You need a semicolon.